# How to implement Single Sign On using Spring and Active Directory

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have a Spring based Web App which I would like to implement a Single Sign On solution on.

The basic flow would be:

1) User logs in into Windows Workstation/Desktop PC (authenticating against organisation's Active Directory)

2) User opens browser and navigates to Spring Web App.

3) Spring Web App *somehow* confirms that the user is already authenticated against AD and seamlessly lets them in. i.e. no challenge for username and password. Infact, the Spring web app would NEVER show a login form.

Obviously it's step 3 I am having trouble with.

I have looked at Spring Security, Kerberos, SPNEGO but I think I've just confused myself.

If it makes a difference I am using Java 6, running on Jetty with Spring 3. The Jetty instance will be running on a *Nix machine.

Comment: I have written a custom-component for that. I covers 100 % of your case. Do you want to try that?

Comment: Yes, I would be interested to see that please.

Comment: Contact me through my SF.net mail address: http://sourceforge.net/u/michael-o/profile

Comment: What kind of comment is that? Do you want to share an answer or not? This is an open Q&A site, "contact me privately for an answer" has no room here.

Comment: I second with kaqqao, Michael's comment is not a solution just selling a product (even if he gives the code free). 

@Michael-O could you share your solution with us without asking it from you via any private way?

Comment: @GaborGarami, yes I can but I need to remove company-related code and POMs first. This is why I cannot disclose it right now. It wouldn't even compile without our internal Nexus instance.

Comment: @Michael-O I did not say share us a code if it is contains unshareable pieces. Share at least the idea with us because it can help a lot even without a real code. But offering a private solution is not match with the principles why this whole site exists.

Comment: @GaborGarami, my Spring code is based on my [Tomcat SPNEGO authenticator](http://tomcatspnegoad.sf.net/).

Comment: @Michael-O thanks for clarification. This information would be much more helpful to other visitors than "could you mail me to send a secret answer?" -typed replies.

Comment: @GaborGarami, sorry for the noise. I credo is to release all software as OS from work which is generic enough.

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257969/windows-ad-single-sign-on-using-javascript-and-node has a solution that doesn't even require any special configuration except writing the nodejs script and including the lib. It simply works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have implemented the same thing for my client.  We are using spring-saml in our spring based web application (acts as Service Provider) and ADFS as Identity Provider(IDP).

You can take help from [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html) for configuration part. I will help you out if you face any problem related to implementation or setup issue.

Basically your web-app will act as SP and ADFS will be treated as IDP. You need to exchange both metadata file which is nothing but a certificate for communication.